# file generated by add_custom_command cannot be found within add_subdirectory

Tags: cmake, flatbuffers

I'm in the process of generating an api using flatbuffers within cmake. Now when on top level of the cmake directory tree the api is generated, the include files that should be generated are not found when they are needed in the branches.

./CMakeLists.txt

```
set(INTERFACE_FBS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fbs/testapi.fbs)

flatbuffers_generate_headers(TARGET incl
                             SCHEMAS ${INTERFACE_FBS}
                             FLAGS --scoped-enums --cpp-std c++17)
target_link_libraries(incl INTERFACE flatbuffers::flatbuffers)
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES incl)


#add_executable(testapp app/src/test.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(testapp incl)

add_subdirectory(app)
```

./app/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(app src/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app incl)
```

Running the system like this results in the following error:

```
CMake Error at app/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    /home/xxx/build.test/incl/testapi_generated.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
  .hpp .hxx .in .txx
```

The `testapi_generated.h` can't be found as it's not generated. But it should be generated as the function `flatbuffers_generate_headers` sets an `add_custom_command` for the wanted `.h` file.

When I move the building of the executable to the main cmake file, so replacing the bottom of:
./CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(testapp app/src/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testapp incl)

#add_subdirectory(app)
```

the '.h' file is generated and the simple application builds without problems. Also enabling the subdirectory at that point will result in a working executable. Performing a `make clean` and the building will fail again.

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to first use files created by an `add_custom_command` in a subdirectory?

I've put the whole project into a repository:
https://github.com/CedricSchmeits/file-generation-issue

Comment: What version of CMake do you have installed, and what version is specified in your `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION)` call?

Comment: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)`

Running ubuntu 20.4 so currently cmake is running:
version 3.16.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Milan Š.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20778926/milan-%c5%a0) already stated the problem is caused by scoping. Within `flatbuffers_generate_headers` the files are generated by `add_custom_command` which is the correct way of generating files. Within the desciption of `add_custom_command` this is already addressed with: **same directory (CMakeLists.txt file)**

> This defines a command to generate specified OUTPUT file(s). A target created in the same directory (CMakeLists.txt file) that specifies any output of the custom command as a source file is given a rule to generate the file using the command at build time.

Further on the solution is stated:

> Instead, use the add_custom_target() command to drive the command and make the other targets depend on that one.

This means that implementing another target which is depended on all the custom commands created by `flatbuffers_generate_headers` would solve the problem. Then within another directory the target there should also be made depended not only of the interface library but also of the additional target. using `add_dependencies`

This is solved in the pull request for flatbuffers: [Added GENERATE_ to flatbuffers_generate_headers](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/pull/7845) which is added to release [v23.3.3](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/releases/tag/v23.3.3).

The `flatbuffers_generate_headers` now not only generates the INTERFACE library `${TARGET}` but also a new target named: `GENERATE_${TARGET}`. Which results that only within the sub directory a change needs to be done.

./app/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(app src/test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app incl)
add_dependencies(app GENERATE_incl)
```

Also make sure that you are using at least version 3.20 from cmake as within that version some issues with GENERATE files flags are solved.

./CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR: It's a scope issue, and the "solution" outlined in this answer is not really a solution but a hack which I don't recommend.

---

This is a scope issue. The way `flatbuffers_generate_headers` is written prevents the subdirectory to invoke the correct (sub)commands in order. There is nothing you can do about this, other than "hardcoding the subdirectory in" - **which I don't recommend**.

What I mean by that is essentially the equivalent of copy pasting it into the root `CMakeLists.txt`, but in a more *hidden* way, i.e.

By directly including the subdirectories `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
include(app/CMakeLists.txt)
```

However down the line this may lead to **other issues** because the main benefit of **`add_subdirectory`** is the scope it creates for the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Hence I will repeat myself: **I do not recommend the above and instead recommend moving either code respectively into the appropriate `CMakeLists.txt`**

Comment: can you elaborate on how it's a scope issue? (for my learning purposes)

Comment: Thanks for the work around and I fully agree that this is a hack and will not work for my actual project where the files generated are my top level include files which is used within a dozen sub-sub-directories.

But what actually is the problem within the 'flatbuffers_generate_headers` project?

Comment: @user Unfortunately if I would've debugged this a year ago I would've already submitted a fix, but I was too lazy to do so (this isn't the first time I'm seeing this issue). My hunch was specific to how the variables are populated in [BuildFlatBuffers.cmake](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/CMake/BuildFlatBuffers.cmake). The hunch was that somehow the paths were incorrectly set when called from a different (sub)directory. Thus you generate "empty" (non-existent) `.h` files. As I never needed it that much (small project) I never bothered to try and prove/fix it.